# Live action Disney film about a highschool student creating an invisibility formula

Tags: story-identification, movie

This starred a young Kurt Russell​ as a high-school student, his entry in a science fair (I think) is a formula that in theory could turn someone invisible.

The principal of the school dismisses it all as malarkey but over the course of the film it does turn several people invisible for brief moments, including at the end the principal who insisted it was impossible.

Comment: This seems like a very obvious "let me Google that for you" question. Perhaps you could elaborate on why looking up a list of Kurt Russel releases was not effective?

Answer (score 6):

*Now you see him, now you don't* (1972), most likely.

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0069031/):

> A chemistry student invents a spray that makes its wearer invisible. A crook finds out about it, and plans to steal it for himself.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Now_You_See_Him,_Now_You_Don%27t) has the dean getting owned at the end:

> Just when Higgins tells everyone for the last time that invisibility does not exist, the top half of him becomes invisible, thus shocking the group and winning the top prize to save Medfield for another year.